# Can't hide modal within Layout (wrapper) component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I'm trying to hide the shopping cart modal of an e-commerce store that I'm trying to build on React. When I try to follow the code in the tutorial, the cart modal window does not hide from the display and just remains there in front of all the other components. There's no error that displays btw.  I'm using a wrapper component with the name of Layout here.

Karte.js - the main cart component

```
import { useState, React } from "react";
import Modal from "./Modal";

export default function Karte(props) {
  const [cartIsOpen, setCartIsOpen] = useState(false);

  function functionName() {
    setCartIsOpen(true);
  }

  const cartItems = (
    <ul>
      {[{ id: "i1", name: "Ralph Lauren", amount: 3, price: 14.99 }].map(
        (item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            {item.name}
            {item.price}
          </li>
        )
      )}
    </ul>
  );

  return (
    <Modal>
      {cartItems}
      <div>
        <span>Total Amount</span>
        <span>35.54</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={functionName}>Close</button>
        <button>Checkout</button>
      </div>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

This is the Modal component code

```
const Modal = (props) => {
  return <div className="modal">{props.children}</div>;
};

export default Modal;
```

Lastly, this is the Wrapper component (that the modal is a child component of)

```
import { useState, React } from "react";
import NavBar from "../NavBar";
import Modal from "../Modal";
import Backdrop from "../Backdrop";

export default function Layout(props) {
  const [cartIsOpen, setCartIsOpen] = useState(false);

  function functionName() {
    setCartIsOpen(true);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar />
      <main>{props.children}</main>
      {cartIsOpen && <Modal />}
      <Backdrop />
    </div>
  );
}
```

If it means anything, this is the App component too

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Karte />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} exact />
        <Route path="/checkout" element={<CheckoutPage />} />
        <Route path="/cart" element={<CartPage />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path="/sale" element={<SalePage />} />
        <Route path="/faqs" element={<FaqsPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You're always setting it to true in functionName. Shouldn't you be setting it to false?

Answer (score 1):

The good news is there are multiple ways to solve this. The main 2 options I'd consider are:

### 1. You could move your `useState` into `App`, and pass a `toggleCart` callback to `Layout`

App.js:

```js
function App() {
  const [cartVisible, setCardVisible] = useState(false)

  return (
    <Layout onToggleCart={() => setCartVisible(!cartVisible)}>
      {cartVisible ? <Karte /> : null}
      <Routes>
        ...
      </Routes>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

### 2. You could render `Karte` from `Layout`

Layout.js:

```js
import { useState, React } from "react";
import NavBar from "../NavBar";
import Modal from "../Modal";
import Backdrop from "../Backdrop";

export default function Layout(props) {
  const [cartIsOpen, setCartIsOpen] = useState(false);

  function functionName() {
    setCartIsOpen(true);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        <main>{props.children}</main>
        {cartIsOpen && <Modal />}
        <Backdrop />
      </div>
      {cartIsOpen ? <Karte /> : null}
    </>
  );
}
```

And remove `<Karte />` from App.js

Comment: App doesn't have access to that state variable.

Comment: @JoelHager updated with an alternate option that's more inline with the current setup.

Comment: @JeremyBlalock Thank you. #2 worked for me. I appreciate your help

Comment: @JeremyBlalock Also, would the same apply for wanting to display the Cart? Should I just make a function in the Navbar (where the cart button is found) that will set the state to true?

Answer (score 0):

check if functionName is running and setting state to true
current =  Close.
If so change code to this <button onClick={()=>{functionName}}>